# Installing Visual Studio 2022 17.3 with Maui Workload on MAC M1

Tags: visual-studio, apple-m1, .net-maui

I have a 14" M1PRO MAC running Monterrey. I created a fresh new Windows 11 ARM VM with parallels, installed Visual Studio 2022 17.3 (Released version - not the preview), checked the Maui workload.

[VS installer screentshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUZSj.png)

Everything installed without errors.

I launched VS, and NO Maui templates showed!.

Opened the Command Prompt and run 'dotnet new --install Microsoft.Maui.Templates'

Launched VS again and templates were there. Created a Project and it failed:

Nuget restore errors:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier android was not recognized.  MauiApp1    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   112
> Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.  MauiApp1    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   112
> Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier maccatalyst was not recognized.  MauiApp1    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   112
> Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst   MauiApp1    C:\xx\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj  1
> Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst   MauiApp1    C:\xx\MauiApp1.csproj   1
> Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst   MauiApp1    C:\xx\MauiApp1.csproj   1

> Build errors:
> 1>------ Build started: Project: MauiApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
> 1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5): error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier android was not recognized.
> 1>Done building project "MauiApp1.csproj" -- FAILED.
> 1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5): error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.
> 1>Done building project "MauiApp1.csproj" -- FAILED.
> 1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5): error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier maccatalyst was not recognized.
> 1>Done building project "MauiApp1.csproj" -- FAILED.
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8072

Comment: I saw that post, tried it but does not seems to be my case. 
It is a fresh windows 11 with just vs 2022 17.3 installed and only maui workload. 

The only dotnet version installed is 6.0.400.

Comment: I had met this problem few days ago. I uninstalled the VS and reinstall the windows system. And then I got the visual studio installer 17.3 preview 6.0 from the official website and everything worked well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but as of now there seems to be no way to install the 17.3 preview, just the released version and I got the same result. I filed a report and indeed there seems to be an issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Maui-workload-failed-on-Mac-M1-fresh-ne/10118003

Comment: You can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317357/error-building-net-maui-apps-in-visual-studio-for-mac-preview).