# Error building .NET MAUI apps in Visual Studio for Mac Preview

Tags: .net, visual-studio-mac, maui, .net-maui

I've downloaded the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac Preview and attempting to create a .NET MAUI app. I'm not able to build and run the solution as "The solution requires .NET SDK Workloads that are not currently installed."

[image]

If I click on Install, this shows but it doesn't appear to do anything.

[image]

If I go into the terminal and enter `dotnet workload list` that outputs no workloads installed. If I run `sudo dotnet workload install` that outputs `zsh: segmentation fault  sudo dotnet workload install.`

What do I need to do in order to be able to run MAUI apps on my Mac as I was looking forward to developing them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue by doing the following:

I made a global.json with the following contents:

```
{ "sdk": { "version": "6.0.400", "rollForward": "latestFeature" } }
```

I installed the legacy Xamarin iOS SDK option in the Visual Studio for Mac installer.

Comment: Where do you add the global.json? In the solution directory or in any project directory? I encounter a similar issue and I also tried to add a `global.json` file, but this didn't work.

Comment: Where to add the global.json file?

Comment: Where do you add the global.json file?